# How to generate a random 3 letter string and check for duplicates from a range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script which generates a random 3 character string. It's being used within a larger script in which the string gets appended to the next row within a sheet.

What can I do to search the range of previous strings for duplicates and repeat the function if a match is found?

```
 function stringGen(len)
 {
   var text = " ";
   var charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

   for( var i=0; i < len; i++ )
      text += charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charset.length));

   return text; 
 }

   logger.log(3);
```

Example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y_4R9XT5D31wwrbJOq8ClipdmIByLV0-nlTc2wZl-qM/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Original

If they're all in the same range (ie a column or row) you can get the range as an array and then use `indexOf()` to check for a match. Something like this:

```js
function stringGen(len) {
   // assume the array starts in A1 and runs down colA
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

   // getValues() returns an array
   var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues();

   var text = " ";
   var charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

   for( var i=0; i < len; i++ )
      text += charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charset.length));
   }

   // an index of -1 means the value is not in the array.
   if(range.indexOf(text) > -1) {
     return text;
   }

   logger.log(3);
}
```

You could also pull the `indexOf()` check into a separate function and return `true` or `false` based on the result to either accept the code or generate a new one.

### Update

Doug's point below is true, especially if you have a very large spreadsheet. The modified code below would work using a `for` loop:

```js
function stringGen() {
   // assume the array starts in A1 and runs down colA
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

   // getValues() returns an array
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues();

  var text = " ";
  var charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

  for( var i=0; i < 3; i++ ) {
    text += charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charset.length));
  }

  // Loop through every element in the range
  for(var j in range) {
    if(range[j].toString() == text) {
      Logger.log('matched');
    } else {

      // Write one code to the next line and stop the loop
      sheet.getRange((sheet.getLastRow()+1), 1).setValue(text);
      break
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I would highly recommend NOT using `indexOf` in GAS. It's much slower than just using a `for` loop, and GAS is already heavily processing limited as it is. Running JS in the browser would be less of a concern as `indexOf` is actually faster in the browser, but GAS is using some old implementations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the updated version @Brian. Am I right in understanding that the for J loop will return 'matched' in the console log and the script will end there or will it iterate through the stringGen function again? If so is it possible as I'm trying to repeat the function if a match is found without having to run it again.

Comment: Right now, no it wouldn't - you'd need to use recursion to loop through again. An easy way would be to call `stringGen()` in the `if` statement to start the loop over.

Comment: Thanks @brain. However, I'm still facing issues. I tried calling `stringGen()` in the `if` statement but it just continues to run the else statement instead. I've tested the above script where `Logger.log('matched')` is used on the example sheet but instead only calling 1 character from the `for var i` with column A filled with A-Z, but no log is registered either.